# Assigning Engines in Arena

Tags: arena

How does one assign a specific engine to a specific color in Arena?  I load a PGN file and move to a specific point in the game.  At that time I want to assign Engine A to play black and Engine B to play white.  Then when I hit the calculate or demo buttons the game proceeds (after selecting "New Variation").  I've spent half the day searching for the answer with no luck.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for setting up two engines playing against each other? In that case you can use the following in Arena 3.5: Engines > Tournament.

Answer (score 2):

In Arena 3.5.1, go to **Engines**, load the engine that is playing on engine 1 first (by selecting the engine 1 Radio button at the bottom left of the dialogue box) then load the second engine on engine 2.
To Play The engines against each other,  click the analyse button